# How do you compare values (greater than/less than) of strings that have been turned into integers?

Tags: java, date

So, I have to make a code that takes in 2 dates (month/day/year) from the user and returns "true" if the FIRST date is less than the second date. In any other case the date will be "false" or "they are the same". I was instructed that I could NOT demand the user to do a specified format (i.e. mm/dd/yyyy) and that instead I should focus on the "/"s.

The problem is, it always returns the "they are the same" answer no matter what I put in. Any tips and advice are greatly appreciated! I'm just a beginner programmer, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Here's The code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mari_WS15IsDateEarlier {

public static void main (String[] args) {

//initial variables, asks for variable input and determines month/day/year

  Scanner dateInput = new Scanner(System.in);
  String answr;

//splits string input into month, day and year
System.out.println("Enter a month, day, and year(separate with a slash) :");
  String date1 = dateInput.next();
  String[] splitStrings = date1.split("/"); 
     String month1 = splitStrings[0];
     String day1 = splitStrings[1];
     String year1 = splitStrings[2];

System.out.println("Enter another month, day, and year (separate with a slash) :");
  String date2 = dateInput.next();
  String[] splitStrings2 = date1.split("/");
     String month2 = splitStrings[0];
     String day2 = splitStrings[1];
     String year2 = splitStrings[2];

//turns string into integer for testing (greater than/less than)
int mn1 = Integer.parseInt(month1);
int mn2 = Integer.parseInt(month2);
int dy1 = Integer.parseInt(day1);
int dy2 = Integer.parseInt(day2);
int yr1 = Integer.parseInt(year1);
int yr2 = Integer.parseInt(year2);

//Determine if the set of variables is a geometric sequence
if (yr1 < yr2) {
  answr = "true";
}
else if ((yr1 == yr2)&&(mn1 < mn2)) {
  answr = "true";
}
else if ((mn1 == mn2)&&(dy1 < dy2)) {
  answr = "true";
}
else if (dy1 == dy2) {
  answr = "ERROR: Dates are identical.";
}
else {
  answr = "false";
}

//Prints out the answer
System.out.println(answr);
```

Comment: This is tricky if you can't impose *some* format restrictions on the user, because otherwise how do you know if "10/03/2015" is the 10th of March or the 3rd of October?

Comment: did you try to print the value of the integers you are trying to compare, before and inside each `if-else`?

Comment: Ah, sorry for not being clear. We are to code it with the expectancy that the user will enter the month first, then the day, then the year, separated by a slash. 

What we are not allowed to do is request them to do a specified digit format (ex. putting a zero before a single digit month/day. They can put in 03/03/2011 AND 3/3/2011).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great Question and fantastic code! The solution is simple enough, from the looks of your code you simply copied `date1` and pasted for `date2`. However you didn't change all of the variables so the code was comparing `date1` to `date1` hence your error. Make sure to change both `date1` to `date2` and `splitStrings` to `splitStrings2`.

Also just a little suggestion specific to your code, I would look again at the identical dates if statement as you are only comparing days. Try `date1=1/2/2` and `date2=2/2/2` and you will see the issue!

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! I identified my error and it worked perfect after that, plus your tip on my code helped me fix the issue with my if statements that I hadn't noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Watch-out for the 2nd date, you need to change `date1.split("/");` with `date2.split("/")`

Replace your 2nd date top two lines with following:

```
String date2 = dateInput.next();
String[] splitStrings2 = date2.split("/");
```

Comment: Thanks for this fix! I was able to identify the problem with this (: 
Yesterday I started to panic, because I thought maybe when strings are turned into integers don't keep their proper values haha